# Vala 'hello world' example gives warning about g_type_init

Tags: compiler-warnings, glib, vala

Compling this "hello world" example found [at the Gnome Wiki Vala Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial) gives me a warning.

```
class Demo.HelloWorld : GLib.Object {

    public static int main(string[] args) {

        stdout.printf("Hello, World\n");

        return 0;
    }
}



/home/scooter3/code/vala/hello_world.vala.c:55:2: warning: ‘g_type_init’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:667) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  g_type_init ();
```

I would like to either modify the program or install some other version of the a lib in order to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, it's possible to have multiple version of valac installed on the same system.

You could explicitly compile with `valac-0.30` or `valac-0.20` (etc.). Your Linux distribution (apparently Ubuntu) has a package that manages a symlink from `/usr/bin/valac` to one of the installed vala compilers.

Explanation for the concrete warning you were seeing:

Older versions of glib / gobject (which is the basic OOP system used by Vala) needed this call to `g_type_init` in order to work and the Vala compiler tries to keep the code compatible with older versions as well.

You can explicitly disable this behavior with `--target-glib=2.44` (or whatever minimum version of glib you want to support).

However in newer valac versions this warning is fixed by using the GLIB_CHECK_VERSION macro, i.e.:

```
#if !GLIB_CHECK_VERSION (2,35,0)
        g_type_init ();
#endif
```

This check avoids calling `g_type_init` if glib is at least version 2.35.

For C compiler warning in general:

Only very trivial Vala programs don't generate C compiler warnings, you have to carefully scan compiler warnings for their origin (valac or gcc). Usually you only have to care about warnings outputed by valac, not those by your C compiler (like gcc).

There is an exception to this rule if you write `.vapi` files where the warnings of the C compiler matter a lot more and can point to errors in the vapi files. (vapi files are used to make C libraries accessable to Vala).

Answer (score 0):

I must have previously installed vala, as valac --version gave

> Vala 0.20.1

I thought I had installed everything with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team 
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8 vala-0.30 valadoc
```

but I needed to also do

> sudo apt-get install valac

to get the Vala 0.30.0 version of the compiler. Once I did that the warning went away.